# NTP is running, Clock not synced. Manual DOES work

Tags: linux, ntp, time-synchronization

An ubuntu server is running ntp, and connected to the internet. Still, the system clock is about 30 minutes wrong and gets bigger over time.

```
$ service ntp status
NTP server is running..
```

Output of **ntpq -p**

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter

mail.thefrown.n .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
193.1.12.167    .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
tshirt.heanet.i .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
chilipepper.can .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Which makes it look like a firewall issue? Funny thing is, When I stop ntp and run the following command

```
ntpdate -u 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
14 Jul 09:27:40 ntpdate[3664]: step time server 217.198.219.102 offset -21.831200 sec
```

The time DOES get adjusted, which would make me believe that it's not a firewall issue?

Comment: `ntpdate` is _not_ `ntp`. What's in your ntp logs? When did you start ntpd? It takes some time to adjust stratum and so on. Also try with different time providers, like `pool.ntp.org`

Comment: Is `0.europe.pool.ntp.org` configured in your `/etc/ntp.conf`? Did you try to `ntpdate -u ...` the servers that get listed with ntpq -p? Also add `iburst` on the server line in `/etc/ntp.conf`.

Comment: Most likely it is a firewall issue.  With the `-u` option `ntpdate` uses a random source port, but ntpd always uses the UDP port 123 for client requests. Check if `ntpdate` without `-u` works.

Comment: @mlichvar: That deserves turning into an answer, because it's almost certainly the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.INIT. refid actually means the remote is still in an initialized state and has not received packets or pulses yet. It could be network traffic not allowed such as a firewall, but not necessarily.

30 minutes offset is beyond ntpd panic threshold. (Did you mean seconds? The offset in your ntpdate output is only tens of seconds.) Depending on configuration, it may only step the clock once, or refuse and quit. Several operating systems instead call ntpdate first before ntpd.

As mlichvar mentioned, both ntpdate and ntpd may be selecting 123 as the source port.

In addition, ntpdate refuses to adjust when "the NTP socket is in use", which is another reason why ntpd needs to be stopped first.  Which is a useful safety mechanism if you do not want the time to be stepped like on a database server.